# Is a server responding to port 443 an indicator that things are fine?

Tags: monitoring, uptime

I've tried setting up a uptime monitor on my CDN, to keep track of response times and to get notified if something were to happen to it. Problem is; my checks are filling the report logs with junk. There is nothing strange about that, the check is making a HEAD request to some URL and it gets logged.

But; this means that the cache hit value gets either very high or very low. And this value is a bit interesting on a CDN so would like to avoid that. A port monitor does not leave any trace in the logs.

So then comes my question:

Is a monitor for port 443 a (at least somewhat) good indicator that the web server is fine? Would it catch a 500 error?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring port 80, the standard port for HTTP?

Comment: I have; but this server also shares secure assets. Which is why I am monitoring the HTTPS port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put up a port check on 443, and a http test. And after 2.5 months of testing I can conclude that; no, it is not a good indicator.

During the 2.5 months of testing the port test has not failed once, while the http test has six incidents:

```
4 x 503
1 x 500
1 x Connection timeout
```